# FFTW - Is fftw_alloc() necessary?

Tags: c, fftw

The docs for FFTW say that fftw_alloc() ensures proper memory alignment.  Are there risks associated with using stack variables for the input/output of a given FFTW plan?  Will FFTW just run slower, or will it not run at all?

e.g. Is the below C code not recommended?

```
    int main()
    {
       fftw_complex in[1024];
       fftw_complex out[1024];
    
       fftw_plan my_plan;
    
       my_plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(1024, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    
       fftw_execute(plan);
    }
```

Comment: FWIIW, you can align stack arrays with `__attribute__((aligned(x)))` or equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

http://www.fftw.org/doc/SIMD-alignment-and-fftw_005fmalloc.html

> A program linking to an FFTW library compiled with SIMD support can
>   obtain a nonnegligible speedup for most complex and r2c/c2r
>   transforms. In order to obtain this speedup, however, the arrays of
>   complex (or real) data passed to FFTW must be specially aligned in
>   memory (typically 16-byte aligned), and often this alignment is more
>   stringent than that provided by the usual malloc (etc.) allocation
>   routines.
>
> In order to guarantee proper alignment for SIMD, therefore, in case
>   your program is ever linked against a SIMD-using FFTW, we recommend
>   allocating your transform data with fftw_malloc and de-allocating it
>   with fftw_free. These have exactly the same interface and behavior as
>   malloc/free, except that for a SIMD FFTW they ensure that the returned
>   pointer has the necessary alignment (by calling memalign or its
>   equivalent on your OS).

"Necessary"?  No

"Well advised?"  Yes - most definitely:)

Comment: Thanks.  We're using this on the Beagleboard xM, which has ARM NEON SIMD instruction set.